# How to use symbolizer in openlayers3

Tags: style, openlayers

How to use symbolizer in openlyers3? I need to display my line with double dashed.

We have option in 2 like symbolizer : {strokeDashstyle:"dash"}

Please help me..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a **lineDash** option under ol.style.Stroke
See:
http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/apidoc/ol.style.Stroke.html 
(you'll need to untick stable at the top right)

E.g.

```
stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
  color: 'blue',
  lineDash: [4],
  width: 3
})
```

Take a look at the triangular polygon in blue at http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/geojson.html

The lineDash type is an array describing the dash pattern.